# Copying data from one AudioSampleBuffer to another in a different class

Tags: c++, class, audio, buffer, juce

I have two separate AudioSampleBuffer objects in two separate classes. Here is the private section of the first class which is called TransportBar.h:

```
private:
Atomic<int> playState;
Atomic<int> soloState;
Atomic<int> muteState;

unsigned int bufferPosition;
AudioSampleBuffer masterBuffer;
static const int bufferSize = 352800; //constant
```

and here is the private section of the section class which is called Looper.h:

```
private:  
//Shared data
Atomic<int> recordState;
Atomic<int> playState;

//Audio data
static const int bufferSize = 352800; //constant
unsigned int bufferPosition;
AudioSampleBuffer audioSampleBuffer;
```

The application I am creating has 4 tracks which record to audioSampleBuffer. I then want a "master" play button, which plays all this data. Therefor what I need to do is copy the data from audioSampleBuffer to masterBuffer. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AudioSampleBuffer` is simply a `typedef` for `AudioBuffer<float>`, the documentation for which can be found [here](http://www.juce.com/doc/classAudioBuffer). Inside there you will see the `copyFrom` member function. There are several overloads for this function, one of which takes an `AudioBuffer<T>` as its source buffer.

To get access to the `AudioSampleBuffer` so you can copy it, you must do one of the following:

- Make it public (or protected if you're in a derived type)
- Create an getter function
- Make the other class a friend
- Use another instance of the same class to access the member

It's worth asking yourself whether or not this is an architectural problem too; could this problem have been avoided entirely with a better design?

Comment: Cheers, there is also the makeCopyOf member function that looks like it may be useful. However the problem I have is that the two buffers are in separate .h files so I can't access the buffer I want to copy from. Any suggestions?

Comment: This is the way to do it! However when I try to use masterBuffer for the output, it doesn't seem to work. That's another issue though. Cheers!